# ¿Como puedo pasar el Path de un archivo por linea de comandos a mi aplicación?

Tags: c#

En la siguiente imagen, asocio una extensión e icono a mi aplicación.

*Captura de pantalla:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer click en cualquier archivo `.jll` se abre mi `App`; hasta aquí perfecto.

Ahora lo que nesecito es que al hacer click en el archivo y abra la la `APP` ésta reciba el Path del Archivo para leer sus valores.

¿Cómo puedo pasar el path de un archivo por línea de comandos a mi aplicación?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Que tal si pruebas así, en mi computadora funciono bien, tanto abriendo con click derecho como con doble click.

```
var argumentos = Environment.CommandLine.Split(new char[] {'"'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Console.WriteLine("Tu Programa---> " + argumentos[0]);
if (argumentos.Length == 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine( "El Archivo---> " + argumentos[2]);

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos opciones:

1- Usar [`GetCommandLineArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

2- En `Program.cs`, el método `Main` puede recibir como parametro los argumentos de linea de comandos:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //En args[] tienes los argumentos  
}
```

Si no recuerdo mal, al llamarse tu aplicación mediante una asociacion de archivo, debes recibir el path como segundo argumento.

Comment: Es como segundo argumento. Esperando la respuesta del OP y verificar que el archivo no abre por defecto con la _Biblioteca de compatibilidad de implementación de la aplicación ClickOne._ Porque en ese caso no reconoce los argumentos.

Comment: Tienes razon @Davlio, segundo argumento, el primero debe ser el nombre de la aplicación.

Comment: Cuando le doy clikc Izquierdo en el archivo me pasa un solo parametro que es la (ruta donde se encuentra el ejecutable o donde esta instalado el programa) si le doy clikc derecho Abrir Con  alli me pasa 2 parametros y el segundo si es la ruta del archivo .jll que nesecito leer ,
Como Corrico lo del Click Izquierdo???

Comment: Es posible que sea un tema de permisos, ya que que con doble click debería tambien pasar el path. Intenta modificar el archivo `tuaplicacion.manifest` ,descomenta esta linea `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` y prueba a reinstalar la aplicación,a ver si asi te funciona.

Comment: Hola ... highestAvailable y requireAdministrator me devuelve que no c puede ejecutar la App ....Voy a ofrecer recompesa haber si alguin me soluciona este problemita

Comment: Puedes probar este codigo a ver si te funciona? Comprueba si en `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0]` te llega el fichero. No puedes depurarlo esto, debes añadirlo a tu app y probarlo una vez instalada, ya que solo funciona para apps clickonce